# MySQL DML Triggers

Tags: mysql, triggers

I know MySQL triggers are DML only (update, delete, insert) triggers.  In SQL Server, triggers can be done "After" or "Instead of" in relation to the statement it is performed on.  SQL Server doesn't support "Before" triggers.  What kind of triggers are MySQL DML triggers considered as: "After", "Instead of", or "Before"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [`CREATE TRIGGER` docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-trigger.html):

> `trigger_time` is the trigger action time. It can be `BEFORE` or `AFTER` to
>   indicate that the trigger activates before or after each row to be
>   modified.